# Adding message to a Queue that is full

Tags: ibm-mq

When I push a message in to a Q and the Queue is full, I get a MQRC_Q_FULL error.  When I retry after sleeping for a few secs I get a MQRC_HMSG_ERROR (2460) error msg. Does adding an message to a full Q make the message handle invalid?

Comment: I used MQv75 .NET interface to test. But I keep getting MQRC_Q_FULL reason code every time I try. I don't use set message properties on the message I am putting. What interface are you using? C/Java? Can you please post sample code?

Comment: As @Shashi said, you should always get a MQRC_Q_FULL reason code. I think the qmgr handle or you are retrying where the qmgr handle is out of scape. check your code. http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.amqzao.doc%2Ffm20260_.htm

Comment: Voting to close as abandoned.  It is not possible to answer without more information.